# UITextView linkTextAttributes link highlight color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

Is there a way to set the highlight/background color and link text color when a link is pressed down in a `UITextView`? 
I've tried setting `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` to `linkTextAttributes` but that does nothing for the background color, pressed down or not.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Nope. Stuck with the default gray highlight

Comment: Still not working. Have to manually add as attributedText...